# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: No public static field named [resultRow] was found on class [servlets.Controller]

Tags: jsp, servlets, tomcat8

I'm trying to use an ArrayList, populated with database entries, to fill a jsp webpage on the server. I have tried multiple solutions to get this to work, and nothing came of it.

My variables are declared as such:

```
Connection con = null;
Statement stmt = null;
private static ResultSet result = null;
Statement stmt2 = null;
private static ResultSet inventory = null;
public static ArrayList<String> dbEntries = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I have an init method, declared and ran as such:

```
public void init(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    new CreateCharacters();
    new CreateInventories();

    try
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(new FileInputStream("WebContent" + File.separator + "files" + File.separator + "dbprops.properties"));


        Class.forName(props.getProperty("Driver"));
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(props.getProperty("URL"), props);

        stmt = con.createStatement();
        result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Characters_");
        stmt2 = con.createStatement();
        inventory = stmt2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Inventories_ AS i LEFT JOIN Characters_ AS c ON i.characterID=c.characterID");
        while(result.next())
        {
            dbEntries.add(String.valueOf(result.getInt(1)));    // characterID
            dbEntries.add(result.getString(2));                 // playerName
            dbEntries.add(result.getString(3));                 // characterName
            dbEntries.add(String.valueOf(result.getInt(4)));    // STR
            dbEntries.add(String.valueOf(result.getInt(5)));    // CON
            dbEntries.add(String.valueOf(result.getInt(6)));    // DEX
            dbEntries.add(String.valueOf(result.getInt(7)));    // INT
            dbEntries.add(String.valueOf(result.getInt(8)));    // WIS
            dbEntries.add(String.valueOf(result.getInt(9)));    // CHA
            request.setAttribute("resultRow", dbEntries);
            dbEntries.clear();
        }
        while(inventory.next())
        {
            dbEntries.add(String.valueOf(inventory.getInt(1)));     // inventoryId
            dbEntries.add(String.valueOf(inventory.getInt(2))); // characterId
            dbEntries.add(inventory.getString(3));                  // mainHand
            dbEntries.add(inventory.getString(4));  // offHand
            dbEntries.add(inventory.getString(5));  // armor
            dbEntries.add(inventory.getString(6));  // carryMass
            dbEntries.add(inventory.getString(7));  // contents
            request.setAttribute("resultInventory", dbEntries);
            dbEntries.clear();
        }
        RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        dispatch.forward(request, response);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is supposed to create two scoped variables - resultRow and resultInventory.

Here is the JSP snippet causing the problem:

```
<tr class = dbCharacters>
        <td><input type=text name='ID${Controller.resultRow[0]}' form ='currentCharacter' value='${Controller.resultRow[0]}'></td>
        <td><input type=text name='Player${Controller.resultRow[0]}' form ='currentCharacter' value='${Controller.resultRow[1]}'></td>
        <td><input type=text name='Character${Controller.resultRow[0]}' form ='currentCharacter' value='${Controller.resultRow[2]}'></td>
        <td><input type=text name='Strength${Controller.resultRow[0]}' form ='currentCharacter' value='${Controller.resultRow[3]}'></td>
        <td><input type=text name='Constitution${Controller.resultRow[0]}' form ='currentCharacter' value='${Controller.resultRow[4]}'></td>
        <td><input type=text name='Dexterity${Controller.resultRow[0]}' form ='currentCharacter' value='${Controller.resultRow[5]}'></td>
        <td><input type=text name='Intelligence${Controller.resultRow[0]}' form ='currentCharacter' value='${Controller.resultRow[6]}'></td>
        <td><input type=text name='Wisdom${Controller.resultRow[0]}' form ='currentCharacter' value='${Controller.resultRow[7]}'></td>
        <td><input type=text name='Charisma${Controller.resultRow[0]}' form ='currentCharacter' value='${Controller.resultRow[8]}'></td>
        <td><button onclick = 'ShowInventory(${Controller.resultRow[0]})'>Inventory</button></td>
        <td><input type=submit form = 'currentCharacter' value=Update name='Update${Controller.resultRow[0]}'></td>
        <td><input type=submit form = 'currentCharacter' value=Delete name='Delete${Controller.resultRow[0]}'></td>
    </tr>
```

However, my jsp simply refuses to read resultRow and resultInventory. I have tried multiple solutions to get this to work:

- Moving the init code to the doGet() method has the same result.
- Using "dbEntries" on it's own results in no error, but the tables are blank, even when the dbEntries.clear() statements are removed.

UPDATE: I think I have deduced the reason for the errors. The JSP EL is trying to find an actual variable named resultRow/resultInventory when I use Controller.resultRow/resultInventory. However, the attribute is not stored as such; removing the "Controller" prefix seems to have solved the exception. However, the information that is supposed to be present is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. If you have run into the same problem as I did, look here:

What I was doing wrong was I was loading the JSP directly from my browser, which meant my Servlet was not even getting called! To fix the issue, I changed the name of the jsp to "output.jsp" (it can literally be anything), then create a startup page (index.html). The html is then written to send a GET request to the Servlet, which is then dispatched to the JSP.